How to do the $\epsilon-N$ proof of alimit with square roots?
I was practicing formal definitions of a limit and I put myself this excercise $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}  \frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}}{x} = 1 $$
I've tried different things but I always end up with $$\epsilon >\frac{x}{x}$$ and  I know it's wrong but i don't get it.

You don't tell us how you get it, so we can't help you figure out what you are doing wrong. Show your work.

Sorry for being so vague but i finally got it.
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}  \frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}}{x} = 1$$
$$ |{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}-x}{x}} |< \epsilon$$
Then we have to rationalise which is what i wasn't doing correctly
$$ |{\frac{x^2+3-x^2}{x(\sqrt{x^2+3}+x)}{}} |< \epsilon$$
$$ |{\frac{3}{x(\sqrt{x^2+3}+x)}{}} |< \epsilon$$
In order to simplify more we use that :
$$ |{\frac{3}{x(\sqrt{x^2+3}+x)}{}} |< |{\frac{3}{x(\sqrt{x^2})}{}} |<\epsilon$$
Now considering that the N we look for is less than x. We can say
$${\frac{3}{x(\sqrt{x^2})}{}}<|{\frac{3}{N^2}{}} |<\epsilon$$
And from this we have: $$ N= \sqrt{\frac{3}{\epsilon}}$$
